# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel code I use `DB` to access to database. In controller function named `showTeacherList` I am trying to get all works of every teacher. But Laravel returns this error. When I dump query, copy past it to `phpmyadmin` and run, it works. My code:

```
function showTeacherList($login){
    $select_result = DB::select('select id, name from kafedra where login = ?', [$login]);
    $kafedra_id = $select_result[0]->id;
    $teachers = DB::select('select id, name from teacher where kafedra_id = ?', [$kafedra_id]);
    $teacher_works = [];
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($teachers as $teacher) {
        $teacher_works[$i] = DB::select('select * from work where teacher_id = ?' [$teacher->id]);
        $i++;
    }
    return view('kafedra/teacher_list', ['login' => $login, 'name' => $select_result[0]->name, 'teachers' => $teachers, 'teacher_works' => $teacher_works]);
}
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: Please provide the full and exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your `DB::select` statement, specifically within your `foreach` loop. You've missed a comma separating your `query` and `bindings`.

Replace:

```
$teacher_works[$i] = DB::select('select * from work where teacher_id = ?' [$teacher->id]);
```

With:

```
$teacher_works[$i] = DB::select('select * from work where teacher_id = ?', [$teacher->id]);
```